# Creating multiple arrays from one array, based on values in another array - python

Tags: python, arrays

The situation is the following:

Lets say I have two arrays, x and y:
Input:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
y = [2,6,9,13]
```

Expected output:

```
arr1 = [2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [6,7,8]
arr3 = [9,10,11,12]
```

I would like to create a python script that can let me split up array x into multiple arrays based on the values of array y as the end points.

So x will split up between 2 and 6, then between 6 and 9, then between 9 and 13 in this example.

I am not sure how to get started on this, I am a beginner. I would appreciate the help and I would love to know how you broke down the problem to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Could you define the rules for us as it's not obvious?

Comment: In arr1, 2 is the starting point whereas in arr2 and arr3, 9 and 13 are ending points of y

Comment: shouldn't arr1 be equal to [2,3,4,5,6] then, as I understand your values in y should determine end/start values of the output lists

Comment: sorry! just fixed what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of x based on value in y and then use indexing

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    arr.append(x[x.index(y[i]):x.index(y[i+1])])

arr

[[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

This works if there are duplicates in the array,

```
x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15]
y = [2,6,9,13]

arr = []
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    arr.append(x[x.index(y[i]):x.index(y[i+1])])

[[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 7, 8], [9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For `x` sorted, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split `x` using the indices where `y` is contained in `x`:

```
import numpy as np

i = np.searchsorted(x, y)
np.split(x,i+1)[1:-1]
# [array([3, 4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12, 13])]
```

Comment: My bad! Yeah I fixed the response

Comment: This code doesn't look at values in y at all, try the same code for x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

Comment: Updated. Same idea but finding the indices through searchsorted @vaishal

Answer (score 0):

You are somewhat inconsistent in your expected output, or I don`t get the pattern behind it, but this should get you close to what you want

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
y = [2,6,9,13]

m = []

for i in range(len(y) - 1):
    m += [x[y[i] - 1:y[i+1] - 1]]

print(m)
```

Output

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: This code doesn't look at values in y at all, try the same code for x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

Comment: It does but interprets them as indices, the example was kind of vague on what was expected.